# Easy way to re-generate default database.yml in a Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3

It is a general best practice to not track the `config/database.yml` file in version control system (p.e. git). If I clone a project this file is missing and has to be re-created. I did so by copying for another project in the past.

Is there an easier way? Using a generator for instance?

Answer (score 2):

You could try naming the file database.yml.example , keeping it in the version control . Then you should instruct Capistrano to copy database.yml.example to database.yml . Anyway , it'll better if you move your usernames , passwords , secret tokens etc. to environmental variables . Then in your *.yml files (in case of open-source project ) people will see :

```
username: ENV["USERNAME"]
password: ENV["PASSWORD"]
```

Ryan Bates explains all the steps in this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-revised?view=asciicast) .

Comment: That would be a solution if the project belongs to me. Most of the time it isn't. There is no `.example` file.

Comment: In this case it's normal to create your own database config file , depending on what database you're using . The easiest way is what you've mentioned - copy from a working project . I don't think there is a generator , the task is so simple .